# Anybody who succeeded in adding "Email Composer" Cordova plugin to Ionic 5 project (for Android12)?

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic5, android-12

I have created a simple Ionic 5 app and would like to add the functionality that would allow sending emails (including those scheduled).
I have tried the https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer but found myself stuck with this supporting Android 12. Is there anybody who succeeded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am use Appery.io to do that, they are based on Cordova and I have no issues with their Ionic 5 app working on Android 12 devices.They offer https://docs.appery.io/docs/ionic-5-mailgun-email-sample-app-with-server-code-plugin, https://docs.appery.io/docs/ionic-5-sendgrid-email-sample-app-with-server-code-plugin.  They also offer to try bulk mailing using their SendGridEmail plugin: https://docs.appery.io/docs/using-sendgrid-plugin-for-bulk-mailing.

Answer (score 1):

After searching around for a while, I came across Simon Grimm's video in which he added this exact plugin to an Ionic/Capacitor project. Prior to finding the video I was having trouble figuring out how to add the Android configuration properly to `AndroidManifest.xml`. When running `ionic cap sync`, I got a warning that I needed to add the following to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
  <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
</intent>
```

But there was no documentation on how exactly to do this. The solution was in the video:

```
<manifest ...>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
            <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

The intent element needs to be placed inside `<queries>`, which should be placed directly within the `<manifest>` tag (and not inside `<application>` or `<activity>`). After doing this, I was able to get the email composer to open up on Android 12 with Gmail.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF0jnmbbpbE